# How does the 4e fighter's Combat Challenge work in the fiction?

Tags: dnd-4e

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “mark” actually supposed to be?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/what-is-a-mark-actually-supposed-to-be)

How does `combat challenge` work? I mean. does any monster know that he was challanged? Is there any difference between marking (challenging) a scared kobold who will run away, a rat swarm, or a lich? How will different types of creature react?